# How to Implement IN operator in MDX

Tags: c#, ssas, mdx

I want to get data from cube based on passed number of customer ids through Web API (C#). As i have search there is no clue to fetch data using IN operator like IN in T-Sql but how can we do in MDX query?. I can filter with single value using `instr`.

would you provide any suggestion how to perform this? May i do for loop and query for single value, store and return, but it will be heavy query or every Single value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In operator can be implement in MDX quite easily. Let say I want to list data for 2011,2012, 2013 . The implementaion will be as follows.

{[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2011],[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2012],[Date].[Calendar Year].[CY 2013]}

Here the brackets indicate that there is a set referred"{}".

Based on the last comment. So lets say you get three id 100,200,300 and you want to have implement IN them.

{[Customers].[Customer].[100],[Customers].[Customer].[200],[Customers].[Customer].[300]}

Comment: may i do this way HAVING instr(1,[Customers].[Customer].currentmember.name, "(000045)") 
  OR 
  instr(1,[Customers].[Customer].currentmember.name, "(000322)")
  ON ROWS

Comment: What is your business senario.

Comment: I want to get customer ids from Web API request and build query based on passed customer ids and return the result

Comment: Does the above help?

Comment: yes, it helps but the reason I was using instr because some of the members have space in them. For example, " (000045)". Is there any other way to retrieve the data apart from using instr?

Comment: I need to see your complete query